# How to use Data Factory's pagination EndCondition on a copy data rest api source

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have API like shown in below. I want to achieve the pagination.

API
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfU7K.png)

I have tried with End Condition with value NonExist or Empty but no luck
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt2av.png)
I have used this because at the end I am getting data as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AacxT.png)

I am not sure how to use EndCondition.Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have applied pagination is correct, but its only application is for 'data'.

As you have only given the EndCondition for the 'data', it is only paginating data values, and the rest of all the data below is as it is. You should also apply or change the EndCondition for the complete JSON file.

You can add the EndCondition on 'status' as well so that if 'status' not 200, the pagination should get applied.

For better understanding, please check the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support

Answer (score 0):

Try the EndCondition  with  data empty:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxKC3.png)

Or save the total pages response in a variable and  then use it in the condition or in the Range option under QueryParameters